# Need explanation to translate

Tags: python-3.x

I am currently learning python, but also other programming languages. Now I've run into a dilemma. I have the following code that i need to translate to three different programming languages, but before I do that I want to know in detail how the code works. The code (in python) is :

```
my_secret_key = 5

def decrypt(secret_string, secret_number):
    result = ""
    for x in secret_string:
        result = result + chr(ord(x) ^ int(secret_number))
    return result

print(decrypt("alq%lv%``k%b`m`lh", my_secret_key))
```

Now I have basic knowledge of Python and understand parts of this code, but the calculation it is making is difficult for me to understand.

Are there people willing to help me translate this code to human language so I can then find my way to translate this into other programming languages.

Thanks!

I have tried to look up the functions of chr and ord, and combined this with the x ^ int(secret_number). I tried to devide the code into blocks which helped me understand parts of it.

I tried just applying the calculation blocks but that doesnt work, it needs the full code to work

Comment: `^` is XOR operation. Google for XOR encryption.

Comment: look in the excellent Python doc for the stuff you don't know

Answer (score 0):

Explained with comments above each line:

```py
def decrypt(secret_string, secret_number):
    result = ""

    # for each character in the encrypted string:
    for x in secret_string:

        # 1. convert the character to `int` using the `ord` function
        # 2. convert the secret_number to `int` using the `int` function (this
        #    is redundant is this example, as `my_secret_key` is already `int`)
        # 3. XOR the two integers with each other
        # 4. convert the result from `int` back to `char` (actually 1-element
        #    string) using `chr`, and append it to the result string
        result = result + chr(ord(x) ^ int(secret_number))

    # return the decrypted string
    return result
```

Regarding the `^` operator, from [Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#binary-bitwise-operations):

> The `^` operator yields the bitwise XOR (exclusive OR) of its arguments [...]

This means that the result is an integer, whose binary representation will have:

- zeros on bit positions where both arguments had 0, or both arguments had 1
- ones on bit positions where one of the arguments had 0, and the other had 1

Example:

```
argument 1: 001 (binary), 1 (decimal)
argument 2: 011 (binary), 3 (decimal)
            ---
XOR result: 010 (binary), 2 (decimal)
             ^
             bits in argument 1 and 2 on this position have different values,
             so the result is 1
```

You can find more info on the XOR operation e.g. on Wikipedia: [Exclusive or](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_or),  [XOR Cipher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XOR_cipher)